# How to get my webcam working on Skype?

Tags: command-line, skype, webcam

My HP webcam doesn't work on Skype. I have Ubuntu version 14.01 and I don't really want to buy an external webcam. Can anybody please help?

Comment: Does it work in cheese?

Comment: I don't have that

Comment: `cheese` is standard software on Ubuntu, so unless you manually removed it, you should still have it... Please try again by going to the dash and typing `cheese` and clicking on the sole icon still there. If that still fails, go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type `lspci&&lsb_release -c -s`. Then [edit] your question and copy-paste the output of the command into your question.

Comment: I tried downloading it, but it said it wasn't compatible with my laptop